# show that $\lfloor \sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $n\in \mathbb N,$ show that $\lfloor \sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor=\lfloor \sqrt{4n+1}\rfloor$.

---

For $n\in \mathbb N$, let $p=\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor $, then we have : $$p \leqslant \sqrt n <p+1,$$
so $p^2 \leqslant n < (p+1)^2$ and $p^2+1 \leqslant n+1 < (p+1)^2+1$ Then $$p \sqrt{1+1/p^2} \leqslant \sqrt{n+1} \leqslant (p+1)\sqrt{1+1/(p+1)^2} $$
The prolem is that I can't deduce that $$p  \leqslant \sqrt {n+1} \leqslant p+1 $$
Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: $\lfloor \sqrt 3\rfloor=1$ but $\lfloor \sqrt 4\rfloor=2$.

Comment: For $n=3$, $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor=1$ but $\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor=2$

Comment: The thing you want to prove in the beginning is not true. $\lfloor \sqrt 3\rfloor \neq \lfloor \sqrt 4\rfloor.$ So that won't work.

Comment: Quick and dirty graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n5wafnufq4

Comment: $n<(p+1)^2$ implies $n+1\leq (p+1)^2.$ In general, in the natural numbers (or the integers) if $A<B,$ then $A+1\leq B.$

Comment: Thaank yo so mch ! So if this approach is not true how can I solve the problem without it ?

Comment: Do it with the numbers you have, rather than $\sqrt n$?

Comment: @M-S FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%5Csqrt%7B4n%2B2%7D%5Crfloor%3D%5Clfloor%5Csqrt%7B4n%2B1%7D%5Crfloor%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Crfloor%3D%5Clfloor%5Csqrt%7B4n%2B1%7D%5Crfloor%24&p=1), very similar questions include [Quadratic equations and inequalities $\sqrt{4n+1}<\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{4n+2}$ and $[\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}] = [\sqrt{4n+1}]$](/q/760330) and [Proving an identity in floor function](/q/2442533), as well as the AoPS threads ...

Comment: @M-S (cont.) [Greatest integer function](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1726264p11179025), [It's correct this sentences?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1205788p5952436) and [1988 HKPSC Q14](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1459644p8418187).

Comment: the first thing follows from this:  that $4n+2$  is not a square. Squares are $0,1 \pmod 4$